# HelloMapView in android

Tags: android

I am trying to write a mapView application .When I extend my class with MapActvity it will generate an error force to close application.
 And in log chat I got an run-time error like classNotFoundException.

please solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to point out the error without knowing what you've done so far, but at the very least you must add the library to your manifest:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

You should also go into `Window > Android SDK and AVD Manager` in  Eclipse and make sure the device your running is targeting `Google APIs (Google Inc.)` rather than `Android x.x`